# Find all elements that start with 'button-'

Tags: python, regex, selenium

I am using Selenium to try and get all ID elements that that start with "button-". What I have tried so far was to use regex to match the "button-" but I get an error stating that `TypeError: Object of type 'SRE_Pattern' is not JSON serializable`. My code so far is:

```
all_btns = self.driver.find_elements_by_id(re.compile('^button-?'))
```

But as mentioned that raises an error. What is the appropriate way of getting all elements when you don't know the full ID, class, css selector etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `find_element_by_xpath` and `starts-with`:

```
find_elements_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "button-")]')
```

- `//*` will match any elements
- `[starts-with(@id, "button-")]` will filter the elements with a property `id` that starts with `button-`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Except I will be using `find_elements_by_xpath` since I want them all. I need to start looking into using XPath, seems to be the better option most of the time when working with things like this.

Comment: You are welcome, I edited my answer using the `find_elements_by_xpath` instead of `find_element_by_xpath `

Answer (score 0):

Clément's answers works just fine, but there is also a way to do this with css selectors:

```
*[id^='button'].
```

`*` matches all tags, just like in xpath and `^=` means 'starts with'